# LINQ to dataSet: how to grab two columns after a order by

Tags: linq

I have the following schema:

> TierId, CountryCode, CountryName

How can I use LINQ to get an Enumerable collection of 
(TierId, , )

I know I can do the following solution, but is there a way to avoid double ordering?
Something like order col1 and col2 (stick together) by col3 ?

```
 var a = from row in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
         group row["CountryCode"] by row["TierId"]
         into countrieCodes
         select new
             {
                 tierId = Convert.ToInt32(countrieCodes.Key)-1,
                 countrieCodesList = countrieCodes.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList()
              };

 var b = from row in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
         group row["CountryName"] by row["TierId"]
         into countrieNames
         select new
         {
            tierId = Convert.ToInt32(countrieNames.Key)-1,
            countrieCodesList = countrieNames.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList()
         };

var c = from itemA in a
        from itemB in b
        where itemA.tierId == itemB.tierId
        orderby itemA.tierId
        select new {
          TierId = itemA.tierId,
          CountriesA = itemA.countrieCodesList,
          CountriesB = itemA.countrieCodesList,
         };
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to cross join your table to itself, or inner join your table to itself on the `TierId` column? It's not clear what you are trying to do, and from what I am guessing it looks like you have a database design problem more than a code problem

Comment: It would really help if you could reformat your code to avoid it scrolling. Why is so much of it so far to the right? (I can't do it myself right now as I'm about to get off a train, but it would be worth you doing it yourself.)

Comment: Indented. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know. Trying to press eveything into Linq is not always the most readable approach. How about something alternative:

```
   class TierCountries
   {
       int TierId { get; private set }
       public HashSet<string> CountryCodes { get; private set; }
       public HashSet<string> CountryNames { get; private set; }

       public TierCountries(int tierId)
       {
            TierId = tierId;
            CountryCodes = new HashSet<string>();
            CountryNames = new HashSet<string>();
       }
   }

   var _TierCountryMap = new Dictionary<int, TierCountries>();

   foreach (var row in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable())
   {
       int tierId = Convert.ToInt32(row["TierId"]);
       TierCountries tc;
       if (!_TierCountryMap.TryGet(tierId, out tc))
       {
            tc = new TierCountries(tierId);
            _TierCountryMap[tierId] = tc;
       }
       tc.CountryCodes.Add(row["CountryCode"]);
       tc.CountryNames.Add(row["CountryName"]);
   }
```

Not much Linq but only one pass over the table.

Comment: Took your advise. Just for my knowledge how do I attach two columns in LINQ to be dependent in each other and always be sorted together ?

Comment: @user311130: Mh, not sure what exactly you are after. Best is probably if you ask another question with a sample.